# __autoload() doesn't work in included files

Tags: php

I have a index.php file where the function __autoload() is on top.

The function looks like this (I'm using smarty):

```
function __autoload($classname) {

    echo "Loading classname.\n";

    if (substr($classname, 0, 15) == "Smarty_Internal") {
        $classname = "./libs/sysplugins/" . strtolower($classname);
        require_once $classname . ".php";
    }
    else {
        include $classpath.$classname.'.php';
    }
}
```

This works fine in this file.

Further down I have included another file with

```
include './files/otherfile.php';
```

In this file, I'm trying to load a class with

```
$bla = new ClassName;
```

But whenever i load the page i get this message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'ClassName' not found in ...
```

It doesn't even try to load the class with autoload, I don't get a "Loading classname." message which should be there.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: **Note:** `spl_autoload_register()` provides a more flexible alternative for autoloading classes. For this reason, using `__autoload()` is discouraged and may be deprecated or removed in the future.

Comment: What PHP version are you running? Can you confirm it's PHP 5?

Comment: I know, but I had the error with `spl_autoload_register` before and I tried if I would get any other results with the `__autoload()` function, which didn't work either.

Comment: It's PHP Version 5.4.16

Comment: Can you provide a self-contained example that replicates the issue for you?

Comment: I've found the mistake. I used `spl_autoload_register()` before without actually putting the function name in it, so it didnt register my loading function as the autoload function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php#62723 - 8 year old comment: "You have to have the function included in every topmost script." - as everyone else suggested, and the docs too, use `spl_autoload_register`.